# "Взрослый возраст": можно ли так сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, допустимо ли употребление выражения "взрослый возраст"? Мне как-то режет слух, но как тогда иначе выразиться: "Во взрослом состоянии"? Или как-то иначе?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прилагательное "взрослый" со значением "достигший зрелого возраста" имеет узкое значение и ограниченную сочетаемость со словами:

(1) относится к живым (растущим) организмам (люди, животные, растения): взрослый человек, взрослая дочь, взрослая особь.

(2) в разговорной речи обозначает "относящийся к взрослым людям, касающийся взрослых людей: взрослые проблемы, взрослая прическа.

Выражение "взрослое состояние" используется в речи, но, скорее , это также разговорный вариант. В нейтральной речи можно говорить, например, о состоянии здоровья.

И уж конечно, не может быть взрослым возраст, который в этом случае как бы приравнивается к живым и РАСТУЩИМ предметам.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

История со "взрослым возрастом" оказывается весьма интересной и видится примерно так. Слово "взрослый" имеет прямое значение в сочетании "взрослый человек", но оно получает дальнейшее развитие путем переноса по смежности, что для языка весьма типично: взрослые манеры, мой первый взрослый сезон, взрослые игры и пр. А "взрослое состояние"? Пожалуйста, без проблем, применяется даже в качестве термина в учебниках по психологии, например: "Взрослое состояние способно развиваться в течение всей жизни человека".

Ну а "взрослый возраст", чем он нам так не угодил? Тут дело, скорее, не в смысловой сочетаемости, о которой мы можем и не задумываться, а в звуковой: два слова имеют одну и ту же приставку ВОЗ/ВЗ и один и тот же корень РАСТ/РОС, что и напрягает наш слух. И не было бы у "взрослого возраста" никаких шансов закрепиться в языке, если бы не одно обстоятельство: словосочетание с таким значением нам НЕОБХОДИМО, а слово "взрослый" НЕЧЕМ ЗАМЕНИТЬ.

Действительно, мы  делим окружающих на взрослых и детей, двадцатилетний человек, конечно же, человек взрослый, но вот зрелым его не назовешь.Есть детский возраст, и ему должен противостоять этот самый "возраст взрослый". И думается мне, что этот вариант постепенно и незаметно превратится в обычное словосочетание, неправильность которого мы просто перестанем замечать.

Answer (score 3):

Честно говоря, с самого начала не понимал, о чем автор спрашивает. Обсуждение окончательно все запутало.

Можно ли *сказать* "Взрослый возраст"? А кто запрещает? Тавтологии нет, принципиальной несочетаемости - тоже. Путаницы в понимании не вызывает. Какие еще могут быть запреты? 
Взрослый возраст = возраст взрослости.

А вот что касается стиля... Ну да, не во всяком контексте такое уместно. Все-таки это выражение скорее разговорное. В книжном, поэтическом, вообще - высоком стиле я бы его избегал. "Взрослая жизнь", "взрослое состояние" просто "взрослость" - что-то всегда можно найти подходящее и более выразительное.
Но опять-таки это дело автора и его понимания.

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае правильно "в зрелом возрасте". А вообще возраст бывает: младенческий, детский, переходный, дошкольный, школьный, юношеский, призывной, молодой, зрелый, солидный, пожилой, преклонный, старческий...

*Взрослый* означает: такой, который вырос, достиг зрелого возраста. Так что *взрослый возраст* - это "достигший зрелого возраста возраст", речевая ошибка, называемая тавтологией (определение предмета через самого себя: масло масляное).

Comment: Взрослый  возраст  -  это  тот,  что  после  молодого.  Тут  тавтологии  никакой  нет.  Человек  достигший  взрослого  возраста  должен  понимать  и  отвечать  за  свои  поступки.

Comment: Мне кажется, что "зрелый возраст" ассоциируется у людей с людьми сильно за 40. А взрослым человек считается с достижением совершеннолетия.

Comment: Зрелый возраст (он же средний возраст) - от 20 до 60 лет. После юности наступает зрелость. Юность - до 20 лет. Взрослый - достигший зрелости, то есть перешедший рубеж 20 лет. Если хотят подчеркнуть взрослость до наступления зрелости, выбирают другие средства: например, говорят "он был в сознательном возрасте" или "зрелый не по годам". Кроме того (читайте ответ Софии), взрослым может быть только живое существо, которое растет, или предметы/вещи, предназначенные для взрослых (взрослые туфли, фильмы).

Comment: Возрастные периодизации можено посмотреть здесь: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%EE%E7%F0%E0%F1%F2%ED%E0%FF_%EF%E5%F0%E8%EE%E4%E8%E7%E0%F6%E8%FF

Comment: >Мне кажется, что "зрелый возраст" ассоциируется с людьми сильно за 40. А взрослым человек считается с достижением совершеннолетия.    
    
Ой, не скажите...  
(----)  
Среди них были и дарственные  экземпляры,  о
чем   свидетельствовала   надпись  на  крышке:  "Любимому  сыну
Сереженьке  Кастраки  в  день  сдачи  экзаменов   на   аттестат
зрелости". Над словом "зрелости" булавкой было выцарапано слово
"половой".  Сделано  это было, по-видимому, приятелями молодого
Кастраки, такими же двоечниками, как и он сам.  

ИиФ "Золотой Теленок".

Answer (score 1):

Можно сократить до "(будучи, уже) взрослым". Вот так: "Он поступил на службу взрослым".

Answer (score 1):

wiki-статья "Взро́слый":
..."Вхождение во взрослый возраст, в зависимости от местного законодательства, сопровождается получением таких прав, как вождение автомобиля, употребление алкоголя, курение, самостоятельный выезд за границу, участие в политической жизни (получение прав избирать и быть избранным), половые отношения и брак".

А мне тут никакие уши не режет. Может оно и ошибка, однако, по причине частоты употребления - пора в словари. А "более взрослый возраст" как вам? Так этот, вообще, имеет 1.770.000 совпадений на гугле!

Comment: Это ничего не доказывает. В том же Гугле "поднять вверх" - 2 млн 928 тыс. Не всякую глупость нужно заносить в словари. Кстати, правильно - "резать слух", а не "уши". Хотя, если вы утверждаете, что вам "никакие уши не режет", возможно, вам лишнюю парочку можно и отрезать.

Comment: Даже больших писателей *пробивает* на *масло масляное* :  
>К. Г. Паустовский. Повесть о жизни. Беспокойная юность (1954)  
Это глупое убеждение в какой-то мере **сохранилось у меня до взрослого возраста.**

Comment: Да, Паустовский допустил ошибку. И что из этого следует? "Ура! Он ничем не лучше нас"? "Ура! Мы ничем не хуже его"? Называйте вещи своими именами и не ищите оправданий ни себе, ни Паустовскому. А примеров я вам могу привести миллион. То же "поднять вверх" встречается у Аксенова, Войновича, Астафьева и многих других. Я знаю много хороших людей, которые курят, но курение не становится от этого полезным.

Comment: Даже великий лингвист современности А.А.Зализняк простодушно употребляет сочетание "взрослый возраст". Надо бы ему поставить на вид)  
*Поднять вверх* - разве это неправильное выражение?? Кто осмелился его запретить к употреблению, назовите... Карамзин, Лесков, Чехов и Ко писали невозбранно : *поднял вверх*, и вдруг нам выходит приказ от угрюм-бурчеевых : запорю!

Comment: Всё, сдаюсь. Поднимайте куда хотите: вверх, вниз, вбок... У вас такие авторитетные друзья по речевому употреблению. А я всего лишь tat. Только можно мне говорить просто "поднять"? Надеюсь, это никого не оскорбит.

Comment: Смысл-то иногда требуется уточнить)  
Сравните, пожалуйста :  
*Поднял монету с пола*.  
*Поднял руки к груди*.  
*Поднял глаза на собеседника*.  
>Михаил Анчаров. Самшитовый лес (1979)  
Сапожников поднял глаза вверх и стал смотреть в потолок.

>Е. И. Замятин. Мы (1920)  
Кажется, прихожу в норму. Он отпустил меня ― поднял глаза вверх. Голова запрокинута ― и я в первый раз заметил его кадык.

>А. И. Куприн. Поединок (1905)  
Остановившись на откосе, он поднял глаза вверх, к небу.

>А. П. Чехов. Степь (1888)  
Он оставил трубочку и поднял глаза вверх.  

Можно не уточнять, если не хотите.

Comment: Можно  сказать  и  просто  "поднял ",  но  "поднял  вверх"  точнее  указывает  на  то,  как  именно  поднял.

Comment: Да, конечно, лучше всё уточнять, а то не поймут. Нужно говорить: кисть руки, стопа ноги, ресницы глаза, ногти пальцев, опустить вниз, поднять вверх, подпрыгнуть вверх, спрыгнуть вниз, идти ногами, есть ртом. И особенно важно уточнение, когда речь идет о глазах, а то могут подумать, что глаза подняли не вверх, а с пола. А это нарушит целостность художественного образа, ведь герой с выпавшими глазами уже не целый.

Comment: >Дарья Донцова. Уха из золотой рыбки (2004)  
Ну когда она начнет хоть чуть-чуть **думать головой?**  
> Н. Г. Гарин-Михайловский. Студенты (1895)  
О, надо **слушать обоими ушами**, слушать и не терять ни одного дорогого слова!  
> А. Ф. Писемский. Русские лгуны (1865)  
― Так как же по генеральским-то лицам **танцевать и ходить ногами** ― неловко! 

Его величество контекст.